# CSS inheritance and specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm having trouble with a css stylesheet. I've narrowed it down to be about inheritance and specificity in the css styles.

Right now (simplified) I've got an HTML `<body>` that looks like the following:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div class="unilogin-wrap">
        <h1 class="unilogin-h1">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, this is part of a uni-login form that needs to be used on several websites and therefore it has a seperate stylesheet for the specific unilogin style. However in the website stylesheet (style.css) the following is set:

```
#page-wrap h1{
    font-size:18px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

And in the unilogin stylesheet (unilogin.css) the following is set:

```
.unilogin-wrap h1.unilogin-h1 {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#596168;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
}
```

However this won't override the inherited h1 style from style.css. If I put `#page-wrap h1.unilogin-h1{}` instead it works just fine. This is not an option though because it has to work on several websites all with different stylesheets that I can't just change.

Is the any way to override the specificity of the inherited h1 style in the second stylesheet without using inline html styling? (I know that the style="" html attribute has higher specificity, but I prefer to keep the styles in a stylesheet).

Thanks...

Comment: In `unilogin.css` did you mean to use `#unilogin-wrap`? Because in your HTML it's an `id` not a `class`.

Comment: Sorry, typo in my post - I'll edit it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `.unilogin-wrap h1.unilogin-h1 {`

to

```
#unilogin-wrap h1.unilogin-h1 {
```

since `.unilogin-wrap` acts on `<whatever class="unilogin-wrap"` and `#unilogin-wrap` on `<whatever id="unilogin-wrap"`

Answer (score 0):

The more structural solution: giving #page-wrap a class also

```
<div id='page-wrap' class='page_wrap'>
```

and then refer to the class when setting general styles. (Using the id only for absolute positioning and individual hiding / showing)

Other approach is using !important

```
 margin:0 !important;
```

Obviously, if you rely on this much it gets easily polluted and a nightmare to maintain, but for special cases it may be what you need.